# Is newb more politically correct than noob?

Tags: discussion

I've read that newb (pronounced new-bie) is not offensive because it refers to someone being new to something. Noob, however, is more related to the common slang use of "boob" to mean "idiot".

Is newb considered more politically correct, and if so should all occurrences of noob be edited to newb?

Comment: Whether a person is a newbie (noob) is of little importance to us. We judge posts based on their quality and not based on the "level of knowledge" of the person who posted it. Like Makato says in his answer, if you see statements like *I am new to...*, just remove it, its noise.

Comment: @TheLostMind A phrase like "I am inexperienced in COBOL" is useful in framing an answer in an entirely different way than would be done for someone with experience (implied), who may be distinctly irked about advice on their code-quality, when they've been coding with it for X years. "Tidying up" the question, particularly after an answer, I'd regard as problematic. Leaving that type of "noise" can aid a searcher in evaluating the usefulness of answers. I do tend to remove, but only with care, not just blindly.

Answer (score 19):

They're both noise, at best, and offensive at worst.

If the person using "newb" or "noob" is describing themselves, it's clutter. You should edit out statements in a question or answer like "I'm a noob."

If the person using that term is describing someone else, that's uncalled for and, depending on the context, may be outright rude. Again, edit it out of a question or answer, if possible. If it's not possible to edit it out, or if the remark is in a comment, raise a moderator flag: "rude or abusive" if the entire question/answer/comment is problematic, or a custom flag if you need help with something else.

There's a third possibility, as pointed out in the comments: a person describing "newbs/noobs" as a group. For example, "A typical newb error is..." or, "Noobs often confuse X and Y." In this case, an edit is still the best option. Just change it to something that conveys the important point, but doesn't risk insulting anyone and doesn't radically change the post. For example, "A common error is...," or "Users often confuse X and Y."

The point isn't that we need a total ban on "newb" or "noob." The point is that those are rarely (1) necessary, (2) helpful to the point being made, and (3) the best word choices under the circumstances. While SO isn't about being warm and fuzzy, it's also not about being unnecessarily rude or cluttering up the site with "I'm a newb" disclaimers. Avoiding these words helps answer questions efficiently and still be relatively friendly.

Comment: I'd like to note that there is another condition here. *"If the person using that term is referring to "newbs/noobs" as a group, while not referring to any specific user or users..."*. I agree that referring to a specific person, or specific group of people, as either newbs or noobs is uncalled for and offensive, I'm not so sure that using the words as a reference to a certain category of users identified by the qualities implied by those terms should be banned outright.

Comment: @TinyGiant Fair point. Edited.

Answer (score 12):

If you see a line that says:

> I'm a noob in *insert technology here*

or

> I'm a newb in *insert technology here*

then **remove it.**

It's nothing more than noise when describing their problem.  If they have constraints that they have to follow, like they can't use certain libraries or frameworks, that's one thing; saying that you're a complete beginner in a subject doesn't really matter.

Comment: *"saying that you're a complete beginner in a subject doesn't really matter."* I'd say it does matter as it provides context to the scope scope of the question, and helps answerers determine what depth of explanation is necessary, and whether or not that depth makes the question too broad. If someone asks a complicated question, and explains what they already know and what they are having a problem with, you wouldn't edit that out. I think that someone being new to a subject is important information.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I disagree.  Being new to a subject or being experienced in a subject shouldn't generally change the level of help you get.  Experts in a language, tool or framework can generally work with a specific problem description, regardless of the asker's knowledge level.  It's noise because "I'm new at this" is more of a scapegoat to excuse them from adding proper constraints on their question; if they can't make use of a specific technology, framework or approach, those should be mentioned as constraints, and not inferred in one's skill level.

Comment: While I respect your opinion and understand your points, I disagree with your conclusions. I have explained my conclusions, and will leave it at that. I'm not saying that "I'm a newb" is the best way to convey the information, I'm saying that the information being conveyed should not necessarily be discarded.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Please note that our answers are not specifically targeted towards the user who posted the question. We want answers to be helpful to all the people with similar question **irrespective of their level of expertise in that field**.  So, it is OK if a simple question gets a intermediate / advanced level answer. A person who wants to get in-depth understanding  should also be able to find "appropriate" answer on the same post.

Comment: I understand the concept of what you're describing, but I don't think that this is a black and white absolute yes or no kind of thing. I think that in many circumstances that information is irrelevant and should be edited out. However, I also think that in many other circumstances it is useful contextual information when reviewing a post. One example would be If a user who is new to a topic is asking a really weird question, there is a higher likelihood that it is an XY question. Context matters and posts should be evaluated on a case by case basis. @TheLostMind

Comment: @TinyGiant - *being noob* is a thought, it is not tangible. Although it *might* give a subtle hint about the OP's understanding of the subject, it should IMO, play no role in deciding what the answer should be or whether the question is OK to be asked